Why the many accompanying Latin translations of King James VI's elegy for Sidney?
The unexpected death of Philip Sidney in 1586 prompted public outpourings of grief  comparable perhaps only to those following that of Diana, Princess of Wales, in 1997. This grief found expression in several elegies, of which Spenser's Astrophel is certainly the best known. Scholars at both Oxford and Cambridge also published volumes with commemorative poems in English, Latin, and Greek.
The latter volume, Academiæ Cantabrigiensis Lachrymæ, includes a sonnet by King James VI of Scotland (later James I of England), In Philippi Sidnæi interitum, Illuſtriſsimi Scotorum Regis Carmen ("On the Destruction of Philip Sidney, a poem of the Most Illustrious King of the Scots"). Despite its Latin title, the poem itself is in English. A modern spelling version follows:

Thou mighty Mars the Lord of Soldiers brave,
And thou Minerve, that does in wit excel,
And thou Apollo who does knowledge have,
Of every art that from Parnassus fell
With all your sisters that thereon do dwell,
Lament for him, who duly served you all
Whom in you wisely all your arts did mell,
Bewail (I say) his inexpected fall,
I need not in remembrance for to call
His race, his youth, the hope had of him ay
Since that in him doth cruel death appal
Both manhood, wit, and learning every way,
      But yet he doth in bed of honor rest,
      And evermore of him shall live the best.

This poem is followed by no less than five translations into Latin, one by James himself, others by other hands, including Patrick Gray and John Maitland.
I can understand why the king might want to include his own translation into Latin, but I'm wondering about the other translations. The translators could hardly wish to imply that they could translate the sonnet better than the king himself could; yet, not only were the translations made, they were published in the same volume. What accounts for the appearance of several Latin translations alongside James's sonnet mourning Sidney? What rhetorical or poetic effects result from this? Is their publication attributable to existing practices regarding translations of English poetry into Latin? These volumes of elegies also led to the establishment of a tradition of such volumes—they are scarce prior to the ones produced for Sidney, and reasonably frequent after. What impact did the appearance of James's poem and its Latin translations have on that subsequent tradition? Are there any scholarly essays or monographs on this subject? While there are studies of the Sidney elegies (such as Raphael Falco's Instant Artifacts or Dominic Baker-Smith's Great Expectation), I have not come across any that deal specifically with the question of these multiple Latin translations.

I’m not sure that it is fair to call the five Latin poems “translations” of James’ original; “paraphrases” or even “loose paraphrases” would be better. For example, James’ English sonnet begins:

Thou mighty Mars the Lord of Souldiers brave,
And thou Minerve, that dois in wit excell,
And thou Apollo who dois knowledge have,

Whereas his Latin version begins:

Armipotens cui ius in fortia pectora Mauors
Tu Dea quae cerebrum perrumpere digna Tonantis
Tuque adeo biugae proles Latonia rupis

which I translate back into English as follows:

Powerful Mars, whose right is in strong hearts,
Thou, Goddess, who burst from the mind of the worthy Thunderer,1
And thou indeed, twin-yoked child,2 Latonia3 of the rock4
1. Minerva was born from the forehead of Jupiter. 2. “biugae” is a contraction of “bi-iugae” meaning “twice yoked”. I guess that this is a poetic way of referring to Apollo’s being a twin of Diana. But it ought to be “biuga”, which probably means that I have mis-construed it. 3. An epithet of Apollo, from his mother Latona. 4. The omphalos of Delphi.

So the addressees are the same, but they are addressed with different epithets. The other Latin versions follow this pattern of being similar in outline but different in detail. We could explain this in a couple of ways: perhaps James wrote his English version first, and then directed his courtiers to paraphrase it into Latin. Or perhaps James only set an outline, requiring each poet to apostrophize Mars, Minerva, Apollo and the Muses to grieve for Sidney, because of his bravery, wisdom, knowledge, and art respectively.
It’s not unknown for groups of poets to undertake to write verses on the same subject. Elsewhere on Literature Stack Exchange we’ve discussed the Paradox poems of Donne and an anonymous contemporary, the Nile sonnets of Keats, Shelley and Hunt, and the Ramesses sonnets of Shelley and Smith. So it would not be surprising if James had set this kind of task.
One might object that the idea of James setting only an outline does not explain the similarity of phrasing in some places, for example, Gray, Maitland, and Halkerston all have “meliore … parte superstes” (in better part survive). But this is because they are alluding to Martial:

“Pigra per hunc fugies ingratae flumina Lethes
Et meliore tui parte superstes eris.”
“By him will you escape unthankful Lethe’s sluggish stream, and will in your better part survive.”
Marcus Valerius Martialis (c. 100 CE). Epigrams 10.2.7–8. Translated by Walter C. A. Ker (1950). Volume 2, p. 152. London: Heinemann.

The only published explanation I found is this terse comment from Dominic Baker-Smith, without citation:

James liked to set his literary friends tasks and this appears to explain the form of the Scottish commemoration of Sidney.
Dominic Baker-Smith (1986). ‘Great Expectations: Sidney’s Death and the Poets’. In Jan van Dorsten, Dominic Baker-Smith, and Arthur F. Kinney, editors (1986). Sir Philip Sidney: 1586 and the Creation of a Legend, page 94. Leiden University Press.

(Baker-Smith was mentioned in the question, but I guess this one sentence was easy to miss.)

The most famous such contest may have resulted in 11 French ballades, all written around 1487, with the line je meurs de soif aupres de la fontaine (I'm dying of thirst beside the fountain).
